# Safe to install CUDA toolkit separately on WSL2 and Windows 10?

Tags: cuda, wsl-2

I've installed Nvidia CUDA toolkit on WSL2 Ubuntu following the specified instructions from the Windows site. I was wondering if installing the Nvidia toolkit on Windows 10 directly as well would cause any conflicts or override anything potentially for the WSL2 install?

I'll be using the two separate toolkits for two separate purposes (WSL2 for linux libraries requiring the linux toolkit, Windows for things such as VS NSight requiring the Windows toolkikt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't be a problem and this is what you would have to do to use CUDA on the pure-windows side as well as on the WSL2 side.

Other expectations/requirements still apply.  For example the CUDA toolkit versions installed in each location should be consistent with the GPU driver you have already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Nope!

**From this point you should be able to run any existing Linux application which requires CUDA. Do not install any driver within the WSL environment. For building a CUDA application, you will need CUDA Toolkit.**

[Source](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#:%7E:text=windows%2Fwsl%2Finstall-,https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.microsoft.com%2Fen%2Dus%2F,you%20will%20need%20CUDA%20Toolkit.)